# You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [rest-client-builder-2.1.1]. Do you want to downgrade to [rest-client-builder-1.0.3]?

Tags: rest, grails, dependency-management, grails-2.0, restclientbuilder

I am using Grails 2.3.11 and I and I am using the Rest Client Builder plugin in order to consume a restful web service but everytime I run a grails command I get the following message in the console

```
You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [rest-client-builder-2.1.1]. Do you want to downgrade to [rest-client-builder-1.0.3]?
```

After researching I am not understanding what needs to be done. I have seen a suggestion that involves an excludes but that did not work. Can somebody post the answer with the actual excludes syntax and plugin name?

This is my dependency report

[image]

Thanks,
-Viriato

Comment: Looks like you have rest-client-builder-1.0.3 dependency somewhere else. Show your BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: I got it figured out I had a build depedency of rest-client-builder-1.0.3 because under Pllugins icon while expanding it I was not seeing the RestBuilder class of the plugin and I noticed that the 1.03 version of the code did put the actual source code under Plugins icon in Intellij. After that I went blind and could not see it and it was right in front of my eyes. Thanks for your reply it made me look at things more carefully.